# Pub/sub messages remain undelivered after successful acknowledgment

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am very confused why my gcloud pub/sub queue does not shrink after acking messages synchronously. I have a small queue (no more than a few hundred messages) and am using very similar code to that in the gcloud docs:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1 as pubsub

NUM_MESSAGES = 1
PROJECT = 'my_project'
SUBSCRIPTION = 'my_sub'

subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(PROJECT, SUBSCRIPTION)

with subscriber:
    response = subscriber.pull(
        request={"subscription": subscription_path, "max_messages": NUM_MESSAGES}
    )

    todo = []
    for received_message in response.received_messages:
        todo += [received_message.message.data]
        subscriber.acknowledge(
            request={"subscription": subscription_path, "ack_ids": [received_message.ack_id]}
        )
```

I know the messages are successfully acked, because I can see so in monitoring:
[image: ack success]

And yet the queue remains exactly the same size:
[image: unacked messages]

What is going on here? Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not subscribing to your PUBSUB, something like this is in the example.

```
response = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
```

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Comment: This is the solution for asynchronous subscription. I am trying to implement synchronous pull, as in here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have some acks succeeding does not necessarily mean that your whole Pub/Sub backlog is being cleared. Here are a few things to check to better understand what’s happening:

1. What is the value of the [subscription/oldest_unacked_message_age](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_the_backlog) metric? Is it increasing? If so, this means that there is at least one message in your backlog that is never getting acked.
2. Can you check how long it’s taking for your subscriber to ack messages? (This can often be achieved with logging on the subscribing job.) If the time to ack is longer than your subscription’s ack deadline, then PubSub will attempt to re-deliver the message. (See: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) These duplicate messages can build up in the backlog and will need to be pulled and acked themselves.

Finally, per the [Pub/Sub synchronous pull documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull):

> “Note that to achieve low message delivery latency with synchronous
> pull, it is important to have many simultaneously outstanding pull
> requests.

You're only pulling one message  at a time (in your sample, `NUM_MESSAGES = 1`), so it's especially important to always have an open Pull -- at least until your backlog is cleared -- so that Pub/Sub always has a chance to deliver your messages when they're ready.

Comment: Thanks for this. In response to your questions, 1) oldest unacked message is definitely increasing steadily. 2) You can see that these are succesful acks, so the issue is not trying to ack messages after the deadline. And re 3) are you saying if I am not making a pull request with some other subscriber then previously acked messages will not be cleared?

Comment: I should add that no new messages are being published to the topic, so there's no chance the subscriber is simply not keeping up.

Comment: Re: 3, Yes, if you want the backlog to be cleared, you need to keep pulling on the subscription (via either this or some other subscribing job) until num_undelivered_messages is 0.

Comment: I don’t follow. I can’t pull and ack messages one a time?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend extending the leases on your messages so their ack deadlines don't expire (there could be currently some ack deadlines expiring, causing messages to be redelivered).

Make sure you are not nacking your messages, also increase the volume of pull requests you are sending in. It's best practice to have lots of overlapping pulls open at any given time to get better subscriber throughput.